# Jenkins Pipeline Batch file output

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a multiline batch script in one of my steps that kicks off a build process. Problem is, the jom.exe creates another shell prompt where you don't see any of the output of in real-time on Jenkins. Is there a way to redirect output? Here is the snippet of the area in question:

```
    stage('Build') { 
        steps {
            bat """
                echo ${BUILD_DIR}
                call "${VCVARSALL}\\vcvars64.bat"

                IF EXIST "%BUILD_DIR%" (
                    rmdir "%BUILD_DIR%" /s /q
                )

                mkdir "%BUILD_DIR%"
                cd "%BUILD_DIR%"
                start "" /WAIT "${QT_HOME}\\qmake.exe" ..\\FFF.pro -spec win32-msvc "CONFIG+=debug" "CONFIG+=qml_debug"
                start "" /WAIT "${JOM_HOME}\\jom.exe" -j 8 -f Makefile.Debug"
            """
        }
    }
```

Comment: My initial viewing of your code notes that `start "" /WAIT "${JOM_HOME}\\jom.exe" -j 8 -f Makefile.Debug"` has unbalanced doublequotes. Is that intentional? Also `IF EXIST "%BUILD_DIR%"` should be `IF EXIST "%BUILD_DIR%\"`, _as you're checking for the existence of a directory_.

Comment: Remove both `start "" /WAIT` to run `qmake.exe` and `jom.exe` by same command process which is also processing the batch file created temporary by Jenkins in `%SystemRoot%\Temp`. Windows command processor waits for termination of `qmake.exe` before starting `jom.exe` and the output of both executables is written to handle __STDOUT__ of command process processing the batch file and captured by Jenkins. By using command `start` the executables `qmake.exe` and `jom.exe` are executed as separate processes with their own handles __STDIN__, __STDOUT__ and __STDERR__ which you don't want here.

Comment: Thanks guys :) you're golden :D - all fixed. Removed the random quote and removed the start "" /WAIT. Works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments I managed to fix this by removing the random quote and removing the `start "" /WAIT`